# How to fix 404 not found for assets from gem after assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline

When I run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, the assets used from gems is not being included, my website shows a lot of 404 not found for these assets.

```
pnotify.core-4a29894be02cb147dd67c1f609148e95.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pnotify.buttons-19d9aeb87c03cfef956313439afad682.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pnotify.history-d339b3266d96cddfa55c4f0478f9d0ea.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` on production shows:

```
=> ["/vagrant/local/app/assets/fonts",
 "/vagrant/local/app/assets/images",
 "/vagrant/local/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/vagrant/local/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/vagrant/local/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/vagrant/local/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/material_icons-2.2.1/app/assets/fonts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/material_icons-2.2.1/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/chosen-rails-1.5.2/vendor/assets/images",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/chosen-rails-1.5.2/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/chosen-rails-1.5.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/cocoon-1.2.6/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.1.4.0/vendor/assets/images",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.1.4.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/pnotify-rails-2.0.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/pnotify-rails-2.0.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/source",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.2/app/assets/images",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.2/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.2/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/assets/images",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bourbon-4.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.3.1/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.3.1/assets/fonts"]
```

Any help is going to be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `config.assets.debug` options, it was `true` on production server, and theres is no files in CDN.

Simple like that.